# Hide a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I'm trying to dynamically hide a div when a dropdown menu is activated, I am using an applet on my site, and I'm running into problems with it covering the dropdown menu (as it's being drawn ontop of everything).  I've been trying this code and variations thereof and to no avail.  I'm using wordpress as a base for the site...

```
    $('#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.mega-with-sub > a').toggle(
        function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#gameContent').hide();
        },
        function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#gameContent').show();
        }
    );
```

Hope someone can help me here, it'd be much appreciated, the site is:

http://www.nesowns.com

Thanks!

The associated HTML is:

```
<div align="center" style="display:none" id='gameContent'> 
    <applet archive="http://www.nesowns.com/run/vNES_213.jar" code="vNES.class" height="480" width="512">
    <param name="rom" value="xxxx" />
        <param name="romsize" value="xxxx" />
    </applet>
</div>
```

Comment: What is gameContent?  Is it already a jQuery object?

Comment: Is gameContent a variable or the id of an element? In case of the second you'll have to define it like this `$('#gameContent')`

Comment: @JacobM There an error: Error: illegal character
Source File: http://www.nesowns.com/
Line: 77, Column: 2
Source Code:
$(#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.mega-with-sub > a).toggle(function(e){

Comment: Looking at the code of your site it appears that you have fixed the problem, and that psynnott had the correct answer. Could you please accept his answer.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
$('#gameContent').show();
```

and the same for the hide line.  This assumes that the div has 'gameContent' as the ID.

Comment: Well that would depend on what game content is right? it could be `gameContent`, `.gameContent` or `#gameContent`, it depends.

Comment: Trufa, that's why I said "assumes that the div has ... as the ID" :)

Comment: Looks like it is an id if you check the source - <div align="center" style="display:none" id='gameContent'>

Comment: @psynnott: Ohh fair enough, I must admit I did not see you clarification and rushed to comment! lets see what the OP has to say.

Comment: Yeah, make sure you are using $("#divID").hide() or $(".divClass").hide() unless gameContent is an object already... in which case you probably don't need jquery tags

Comment: @Trufa, it was a lucky assumption!  I often do the same and forget to specify the '#' if I'm not thinking.  (I was a bit lazy and didn't click the link the asker included!)

Comment: @Stevaz looks like you're missing quotes around $(#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.mega-with-sub > a) judging by the source on the page

Comment: @Nicky Waites Yep, agreed on that.